# Created AKS using azure portal sandbox for A cloud guru, and getting this error of scope invlaid

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I created aks using az client on a acg(ac loud gurur sandbox), and I am getting this, any idea on why I am getting this?

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zXWEC.png)

Comment: Contact the tech support at A Cloud Guru

Answer (score 0):

***The user doesn't doesn't have rights within that tenant.
Azure resource manager also exposes role based authorization for a user, which would give it rights on Azure resources. It appears the user doesn't have rights to read from that subscription.***

Try to give a required scope to that user . If still it is failing as suggested by `CSharpRocks` please reach out to  tech support at ***A Cloud Guru***.